NVIDIA Kernel is missing. Falling back to nouveau
Я дико извиняюсь за этот вопрос, так как я супер новичок, и это мой второй раз установки линукса.
Я пишу с телефона, так как на ноутбуке отключились все дрова (вайфай, подсветка, звук)
Только поставил свежую Fedora 40 на жёсткий диск через переходник sata USB.
Обновил драйвера на нвидиа, вместо дефолтных, и после перезагрузки - мне выдало ошибку указанную выше.
Что делать - я не знаю. Очень прошу помочь с этой проблемой, так как получить совет не у кого.
Ноутбук Asus fx 705
Nvidia GTX 1660 ti mobile
AMD Ryzen 5/7 (Я честно не помню какой здесь)
*P.S. видел на форумах рекомендует отключить секьюр Бут, но моя материнка не даёт этого сделать, опция просто серая и некликабельная

«опция просто серая» — задайте пароль в биосе, отключите Secure Boot и потом удалите пароль в биосе
